# Intent not sending or receiving integer value

Tags: android

public void Show(int n){
        Intent in= new Intent(this, Results.class);

```
    in.putExtra("Percent", n); // n is inetger 
    startActivity(in);`enter code here`
}

    Intent intent= getIntent();
  //  int num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("Percent")));
    String num = intent.getStringExtra("Percent");
    int num2= Integer.parseInt(num);
    //ch.setText(num);
    //String num= in.getStringExtra("Percent");
    //int n=

   //b.setProgress(num);
    t.setText(num2);
```

Comment: if n is integer in putextra, you should directly call intent.getIntExtra("Percent",0) where 0 is default value, check if this works?

Comment: Didnt work :( same app crash

Answer (score 0):

You can recieve integer value like this:

```
 Intent intent= getIntent();
 int num = intent.getIntExtra("Percent");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `int num intent.getInt("Percent");`